# Meteor application uses 100% of inodes

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, inode

I have a low-traffic production application running on Meteor (Ubuntu) and it's running out of inodes. I recently made a fresh install on a new server with twice the disk space than my previous installation and eventually it also reached 100% of inodes usage. After deleting unused files, inode use dropped to 96%, but it quickly ran out of inodes again. After some research, I found that `~/.meteor/packages` is consuming 80% of total available inodes, and `meteor-tool` uses most of them, but I can't figure out why, and I don't know how to reduce inode usage.

Comment: Same problem here, meteor is using 170% ~200% of cpu no matter what application i run. Did you fix this?

Comment: I could not fix it. The server has zero free iNodes since over a month ago, but it's responding. I love developing in Meteor, but I'm afraid it's not ready for production and we will be, sooner or later, replacing it.

Comment: I totally agree. Please check the following thread https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7491